Can you estimate betweeness centrality from UTM coordinates?
So I have a set nodes (archeological sites). I want to know betweeness centrality for them but I only have nodes (UTM x and y coordinates) not links. Is there a way to know betweeness centrality?

There are tools in QGIS and ArcGIS to build graphs.  For example:  https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html
